# convert number from scientific notation in R

Tags: r, oracle

I have a numeric variable imported from Oracle with 17 numbers, for example: `20172334534654667`.

Now I imported it from Oracle using `dbGetQuery()` in R, but R use scientific notation: `2.01723e+16`

If I try to convert the number using:

```
mydata$var <- format(mydata$a, scientific=FALSE)
```

I obtain 201723345346546**00** instead of 201723345346546**67** 
So, the last two numbers are always substituted with 00.

How can I solve it, possibly without using additional packages?

Comment: perhaps you can load `library(bit64)` and use `as.integer64(yournumber)` or use `format.integer64`

Comment: hi, thanks for your help. I'm going to try this package. But, is there a way to do the same without additional packages?

Comment: so, do you mena to convert it as.charater? if I do that i have the same problem.. last two number are 00

Comment: not possible I'm reading directely from Oracle database using dbGetQuery()...

Answer (score 2):

I was unable to replicate your issue, but I think it would probably be best to use `formatC` rather than `format`.

For your case, it could be:

```
numb <- 20172334534654667
numb

formatC(numb, format = "f", digits = 0)
```

Which gives:

```
[1] "20172334534654668"
```

Hopefully that works for you!

Comment: Eh, was hoping that it might work.  Even stranger that it is adding 1 to the last digit..I'll keep this answer up until an answer is accepted in case it sparks another possible answer

Comment: guys, I soved it declearing in my SLQ query the variable as character:

Comment: so it was sufficient to.